# Regex To Remove Subdomains

Tags: regex

I haven't been able to find a regex to work for my problem. I need to be able to define the TLD in the regex so for example the TLD is ".co.uk". I want the regex to strip all subdomains but keep the domain.co.uk. E.g.

```
subdomain1.subdomain2.subdomain3.domain.co.uk
111.222.333.444.domain.co.uk
```

So in both above examples basically keep "domain.co.uk". The Regex is in the Perl Style Regex language. I think it would be easiest to say find ".co.uk" at the end, keep the 1 word to the left of ".co.uk". If any other period is to the left of the 1 word then delete all those characters. Bear in mind that the "domain.co.uk" can include a dash and numbers etc

Comment: That's fine, but did you try anything?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fS8xR4/1

Comment: Yes I have searched Stack Overflow but nothing seems to work for me. Thanks Avinash but that doesn't work in the program I am using. Its so weird

Comment: @Jon i think you're one already talked with me. Am i correct? Could you post your perl code?

Comment: Yes but I was not getting any answers, nothing seemed to work so I started a new thread

Comment: Jon which program are you using ? @AvinashRaj demo is using PCRE which comes from Perl regexes definition, so it seems it' more an implementation problem when you write it than something else...

Comment: @Jon no problem. Just post your perl code in your question.

Answer (score -1):

I think this could help, it uses lookbehind assertion `?<=`:

```
(?<=\.)[a-z0-9-]*\.co\.uk
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/bA8xX8/2

For the moment subdomain consists only of letters, numbers and dashes : `[a-z0-9-]`

If you want to add more characters put them in those square brackets.